# stalling issue on 1992 Jeep Cherokee (XJ)

Tags: jeep, idle, stall, cherokee

so my 1992 XJ with 4.0l auto trans is wanting to stall at stops & then revs up (1500rpm) then smooths back out only to repeat. we have replaced: air & fuel filters, cleaned throttle body, replaced idle control valve, throttle position sensor & map/bapp sensor with no change. Ideas?

Comment: Disconnect the battery for a few minutes, this will clear idle strategies, restart and let idle on its own undisturbed for 15 minutes so it can re-learn. See if this helps.

Comment: well did that with no change @Moab any other ideas?

Comment: Any codes in the computer?

Comment: its a '92, what do i need to read the codes?

Comment: any OB2 code reader

Comment: ok I know we have fuel pressure & the dist is tight (almost 300,000 miles) Im assuming my mech got no codes. CEL is NOT on......maybe clogged cat? O2sensor? I'll ask him about the codes tomorrow. right now we are thinking maybe a bad "new" mapp sensor  (which is what is supposed to be bad)  so that's gonna be replaced tomorrow. thanks for your help.

Comment: Well it was the ECM after all, jeep is back! Thanks for the ideas & help!

Comment: First one I have seen fail, glad you solved it! You can answer your own question with the solution. Use the "post your answer" button.